# GetX navigation problem with calling onInit() from homePage() again after open subpage directly from link

Tags: flutter, navigation, deep-linking, flutter-getx

I made simply web application in Flutter with GetX. On HomePage I have list of items, previously fetched from my api:
**HomePage.dart**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final HomePageController homePageController = Get.put(HomePageController());

    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            color:Colors.blue,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("Item 1"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Get.toNamed("/details" , parameters:  {'id': '1',} );
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 25,),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("Item 2"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Get.toNamed("/details" , parameters:  {'id': '2',} );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

        )

    );
  }
}
```

**homepage_controller.dart**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
class HomePageController extends GetxController {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    print("init homepage");
    print("fetch items");
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

**detailpage.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:testprojest/detailpage_controller.dart';

class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final DetailsController detailsController = Get.put(DetailsController());
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            color:Colors.red
           ,child: Center(child: Text(detailsController.id!,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),)),

        )
    );
  }
}
```

**detailpage_controller.dart**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
class DetailsController extends GetxController {

  late String ? id;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    print("init detailspage");
    id = Get.parameters['id'];
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

When I click item, DetailsPage is opened with details of this item. This works fine.

But something weird is happened when I open DetailsPage for specific item directly from link (with parameter in link). I noticed that onInit() method from HomePage() is called again, even I open DetailsPage directly, so all items are fetched necessary when I want to load only one item.

What is good approach to do it?

To simplify problem I made simple project

I want to display details for specific item by open link with provided id, but without calling again fetch method from HomePage.

Comment: You might want to watch this video before continuing to use getx: https://youtu.be/zlIgy4es5Ts

Comment: I have tried your given code. It is not calling fetch method again from Home Page.